# Thymeleaf converts integer to float with a decimal point. How can this be avoided?

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-el

If I have a tag like the below and the value `test` comes from a database and is an integer but th:text converts it to a floating point number e.g.....

`<p th:text="${test}"/>`

Where test....

```
{
"test": 5
}
```

the result is `5.0`

However annoyingly if I use a number literal in thymeleaf e.g.

`<p th:text="5+0"/>`

the result is displayed correctly as `5`

I know I can use something like `<p th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(test,0,0)}"/>` however this is problematic as I don't know if the value could be a number or not until runtime and so it will clutter it up with if statements etc. Would be so much better if it finds an integer to actually keep it as an integer (or convert it to a zero decimal text) - e.g. like it does with number literal. Is there any way to do this?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: That's just not true... if the number is of type `int` or `Integer`, Thymeleaf will display it without a decimal point.  Whatever technology you are using to read your values out of the database needs to read it as the correct type and not `float`, `Float`, `double` or `Double`.

Comment: The value is definitely stored as 5 in a mongoDb database. However, we are using a microservice that takes a HTML template and thymeleaf data and then merges them, so it's possible the issue could be there - however I would have assumed it is using the standard thymeleaf library to merge them. I will look into that. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it may be related to Javascript not really having an integer type. But yes, the problem here is in the code you haven't shown us, between the Javascript you're loading and it being put into the model that Thymeleaf is reading from.